# What does "get your hunt on" mean?

Tags: meaning

I searched everywhere but could not find the meaning or even a right pattern for this phrase to fit in. Does it simply mean something like "go hunting"? and why can't I find anything about it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [**"get your hunt on"**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22get+your+hunt+on%22&oq=%22get+your+hunt+on%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j0.9824j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: From the numerous images, I surmise it means: **get** (put) **your hunting *gear*** (apparel/clothes) **on**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Get your ______ on!**

Slang: To do something, to become active in something, to embrace the characteristics of or the attitudes of something.

From *African American English: A Linguistic Introduction* by Lisa J. Green we learn:

> A common phrase that was used in the early to mid 1990s is *get your groove on* to mean to get something going, as in dance.  The phrase has become extremely productive, not necessarily by using words to mean dance, but by inserting different words in the phrase....

The phrase has become very popular and can be seen in advertising for California's Lake Tahoe (Get your vacation on), the Disney movie *Freaky Friday* (Get your freak on) and many others (see [Fritinancy](https://nancyfriedman.typepad.com/away_with_words/2012/02/get-your-x-on.html) for more examples).

While primarily American slang, the phrase has been found in British seas.  In *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire* we hear Fred and/or George Weasley responding to Ron Weasley's infatuation with the Irish Quidditch World Cup team with, "somebody's got their Irish on!"  (Hopefully that's not a paraphrase, I don't have the book handy.)

Therefore, assuming that "hunt" is used in the context of hunting wild animals, the phrase "get your hunt on" would be an invitation to become an active hunter or to supply yourself with hunting products... or, perhaps, simply to dress like a hunter.  The basic phrase is very loosely applied.

Answer (score 0):

**hunt** [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/89513?rskey=qfuUUq&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid)

the figurative sense:

> the act of strenuously seeking or endeavouring to find something; a
>   search, esp. a diligent search

As in:

He was told to get his hunt on, as the X he was seeking was obtainable!